# How to display data in categories from database?

Tags: php, mysql

So my website allows users to create a contacts list and now I have added user-named categories. I am currently displaying the list of contacts using a while loop of the associative array generated from my SQL query.

So it looks like this:

```
Contacts:
Contact 1 
Contact 2
Contact 3
```

Now I have a new column in the database for categories of contacts, and I cannot figure out how to order them by, and display the name of the contact category. I am trying to get it to look like this:

```
Contacts:
Category 1
Contact 1
Contact 2
Contact 3
Category 2
Contact 1
Contact 2
Contact 3
```

My actual code if you need it:

```
<?php
                //START CONTACTS LOOP       
            $contacts_query = "SELECT id, name FROM contacts WHERE ownerid = '$userID' ORDER BY `name` ASC";
            $run_contacts_query = mysql_query($contacts_query);

            if($run_contacts_query){

                while($c_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_contacts_query)){
                    $id = $c_data['id'];
                    $name = $c_data['name'];
                    ?>
                    <li><a href="contact.php?id=<?=$id?>"><?=$name?></a></li>
                    <?php
                    }} //END CONTACTS LOOP 
            ?>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but I would just stay in php mode and echo the `li` tag. Also: is this a new project?

Comment: This is a new feature for an older website of mine. That probably would be a better way to do it.

Comment: Where are the categories stored? Same table / separate table?

Comment: They are stored in the same table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just also retrieve the category and sort first by category and then by name. And check whether the category is different than the last:

```
$contacts_query = "SELECT id, name, category";
$contacts_query.= " FROM contacts";
$contacts_query.= " WHERE ownerid = '$userID'";
$contacts_query.= " ORDER BY `category`, `name` ASC";

$run_contacts_query = mysql_query($contacts_query);

if($run_contacts_query) {
    $currentCategory = null;

    while($c_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_contacts_query)){
        if ($c_data['category'] != $currentCategory) {
            echo '<li>' . $c_data['category'] . '</li>';
            $currentCategory = $c_data['category'];
        }

        echo '<li><a href="contact.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $name . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! This got it working 100% how I wanted it.

Comment: I Wish I could upvote you, but I do not have 15 reputation yet.

Comment: @LandonHammond That's ok. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use different tables in your schema to store contacts and categories.

```
 SELECT id, name FROM contact_categories WHERE ownerid = '$userID' ORDER BY `name` ASC;
```

and then

```
 SELECT id, name FROM contacts WHERE ownerid = '$userID' and contact_categoryid = '$catid';
```

Comment: No need for separate queries even when there is the need to query 2 tables.

Comment: Sure. But if he stores contact and contact_category information in same table, he will need to duplicate data to add same contact in two or more categories.

Comment: As I said: I don't have a problem with two tables (at all) there just isn't any reason to run multiple queries. Which is what you are doing if I read your answer correctly. If not even better :-)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the sql query to get the contacts via their ownerid and the category.

```
<?php
            //CHANGE QUERY TO       
        $contacts_query = "SELECT id, name FROM contacts WHERE ownerid = '$userID' AND category = '$category' ORDER BY `name` ASC";

        $run_contacts_query = mysql_query($contacts_query);

        if($run_contacts_query){
            //You need to echo category here
            print("<h3>".$category.</h3>");

            while($c_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_contacts_query)){
                $id = $c_data['id'];
                $name = $c_data['name'];
                ?>
                  <li><a href="contact.php?id=<?=$id?>"><?=$name?></a></li>
                <?php
                }} //END CONTACTS LOOP 
        ?>
```

Add a category field to your database and call the query with different categories

Comment: Where do you prevent the same category from displaying twice?

Comment: it depends on how you write the code, usually i would put this in a function that takes category and userid as an argument and call it with different arguments