# How to list the product by category_id and order by item_id from database?

Tags: html, mysql, perl, cgi

i have **item** table where columns are:

1. item_id    =      01,   02,   03,   04,   05,     06,     07,     08....
2. ctgr_id    =      01,   01,   01,   02,   02,     03,     03,     03....
3. item_name  =    Wcar, Bcar, Rcar, Abus, Bbus, Qtruck, Ttruck, Ftruck....

And have one more table called **ctgr** where columns are:

1. ctgr_id = 01, 02, 03...
2. ctgr_name = car, bus, truck...

**Now coding are showing the product like as below:**

- car

  - 01 - Wcar
- car

  - 02 - Bcar
- car

  - 03 - Rcar
- bus

  - 04 - Abus
- bus

  - 05 - Bbus
- truck

  - 06 - Qtruck
- truck

  - 07 - Ttruck
- truck

  - 08 - Ftruck

**But i want to show the product like as below:**

- car

  - 01 - Wcar
  - 02 - Bcar
  - 03 - Rcar
- bus

  - 04 - Abus
  - 05 - Bbus
- truck

  - 06 - Qtruck
  - 07 - Ttruck
  - 08 - Ftruck

**from index.cgi**:

```
sub action_index {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->set_property(paginate_row_count => 0);
    my $m_item = $self->model('item');

    $self->set_data(
        'ctgrs',
        $self->model('ctgr')->get_list('del_flg = 0 and show_web = 1')
    );

    $m_item->set_input_params;
    $self->search_execute($m_item->get_list_sql->where("v_item.item_flg = 1"));
    $self->set_data('cart',$self->get_list_cart);
}
```

**from index.html**:

```
<table>
    [% if(@{$c{list}}>0) %]
        [% foreach my $rec (@{$c{list}}) %]

            [% if($rec->{is_item_public}==1) %]

                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                        [# $rec->{ctgr_name} #]
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>    
                        <td class="item">
                        [# $rec->{item_id} #]<br>
                        [# $rec->{item_name} #]<br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            [% end %]
         [% end %]
    [% else %]
    <tr>
    <td>no data</td>
    </tr>
    [% end %]
</table>
```

**from file TinyApplication.pm**

```
sub search_execute {
    my $self = shift;
    my $sql  = shift;

    my @wheres = ();

    foreach my $key (keys %{$self->{search_params}}){
        my $value = $self->param("search/${key}");
        if(defined $self->{search_params}->{$key}->{func}){
            $self->{search_params}->{$key}->{func}($sql,$value);
        }
        elsif (defined $value && $value ne '') {
            my $type = defined $self->{search_params}->{$key}->{type}
              ? $self->{search_params}->{$key}->{type}
              : '= ?';
            my $field = defined $self->{search_params}->{$key}->{field}
              ? $self->{search_params}->{$key}->{field}
              : $key;
            $value =~s/^\s+//;
            $value =~s/\s+$//;
            my @where_or = ();
            foreach (split(/\s+/,$value)) {
                my $replace = $self->{search_params}->{$key}->{replace} || '?';
                $replace =~ s/\?/$_/;
                push @where_or, ["${field} ${type}",$replace];
            }
            if ($self->{is_search_where_or}) {
                push @wheres,@where_or;
            }
            else {
                $sql->where_or( @where_or );
            }
        }
        elsif ( defined $self->{search_params}->{$key}->{default} ) {
            my $field = $self->{search_params}->{$key}->{field} || $key;
            my $type = $self->{search_params}->{$key}->{type} || '= ?';
            if( $self->{is_search_where_or} ) {
                push @wheres,
                  ["${field} ${type}", $self->{search_params}->{$key}->{default}];
            }
            else{
                $sql->where(
                    ["${field} ${type}", $self->{search_params}->{$key}->{default}] );
            }
        }
    }
    if( $self->{is_search_where_or} ) {
        $sql->where_or(@wheres) if(@wheres);
    }
    my $tmp_orderby = $sql->{ORDERBY};
    $sql->{ORDERBY} = [];
    my $total = $sql->get_count(@_); 
    if($total>0){
        my $page = $self->param('page') || 1;
        $page = 1 unless(($page=~/^\d+$/) && $page>=1);
        my $offset = ($page-1)*$self->{paginate_row_count};
        $sql->{ORDERBY} = $tmp_orderby; 
        if($self->{paginate_row_count}>0){
            $sql->limit($offset,$self->{paginate_row_count});
        }
        my $sth = $sql->execute(@_);
        my @data = ();
        while(my $ra = $sth->fetchrow_hashref){
            $self->filter_in_all($ra);
            push @data,$ra;
        }
        $self->set_data('list',\@data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal and *runnable* example, see [mcve]

Comment: I would like to see the search_execute method and the library imports (use blablabla;)

Comment: "  @ sergiotarxz----    search_execute method included "

Comment: @Guspan Tanadi  "Yeah still showing category name. i tried to add this (foreach my $i (@{$c{list}}-1) ) correction. i will delete now this.. "

Comment: sorry it is not perl cgi but take the logic behind https://stackoverflow.com/q/11701746/5628223 if its possible, if it understandable